# Manually making wp_options table

Tags: database, wordpress

So, I got rid of wp_options db table by accident and I am trying to recreate or get the table back.

Is there a way of doing it without reset the whole wp db?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a backup? Ask your server provider if they have a backup.

Answer (score 0):

You can't restore it, unless you have a backup of it. Check with the service provider in case they have automated backup copy. Otherwise, Just try re-creating the table with the following queries. and activate the plugins again.

`` CREATE TABLE `wp_options` (
  `option_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `option_name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `option_value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `autoload` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'yes',
  PRIMARY KEY (`option_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `option_name` (`option_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ``

Put your site url and run the following queries

`INSERT INTO wp_options VALUES ('1', 'siteurl', 'YOUR_SITE_URL', 'yes');`

`INSERT INTO wp_options VALUES ('2', 'home', 'YOUR_SITE_URL', 'yes');`

Then reactivate all the plugins. If any issues, revert back